# Split a string at the first occurrence of a character after matching string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string

The Data:

```
{ 
    \"value\": 17.11, \"year\": 2015, \"sub\": [ {\"x\": 0, \"y\": 0.94 }, {\"x\": 1, \"y\": 1.08 }] 
}
, 
{ 
    \"value\": 17.23, \"year\": 2015, \"sub\": [ {\"x\": 0, \"y\": 0.23 }, {\"x\": 1, \"y\": 1.22 }] 
}
```

I've got a list of JSON objects in a format you see above and I need to split the objects at the ',' between the two objects. The problem is that there are other commas present in the file. Apart from actually serializing the JSON into a List, is there any other way to get this done?

I'm trying to get the data into a string array like:

```
string[] split = json.split(',');
```

Note that the data above is actually all coming on one line, there aren't any line breaks, tabs, or anything. I organized it above to make it more readable.

Comment: I would say for the effort required, you may as well just deserialize it. How many objects are in the list? If less than a few hundred, tje oberhead of deserializing it is minimal

Comment: Is each json object in a single line like in your sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing your own parser would be tricky. It would be much easier if you used a JSON parser. Your format is not valid JSON, but it would be with surrounding `[]`. So if you insert those characters, you should be able to use a real parser:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json

// ...

var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeClass>>("[" + json + "]");
```

Comment: It did end up being too tricky. Although I didn't use Newtonsoft.Json and instead just settled for JavascriptSerializer, this was the best way to go about it. +1 for the tip about the brackets.